# Возможно ли усовершенствование электронной подписи pkcs7?

Tags: криптография, цифровая-подпись, криптопро

https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAdES просто тут написано что было добавлено как раз проставление меток времени, то есть в pkcs7 нет такой возможности?
Если я правильно понимаю вычисляется электронная подпись и потом следующим шагом на сервере TSA можно получить токен и добавить в атрибуты подписи unsignedAttrs, и подпись будет усовершенствована это для pkcs7, в tsa отправляется хеш данных, верно? в cades наверно для этого есть свой атрибут специально предназначенный для меток времени. То есть pkcs7 тоже можно усовершенствовать или нельзя, и нужно для этих целей использовать cades?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Усовершенствование pkcs7 возможно.

Нужна [функция EnhanceCades](https://docs.cryptopro.ru/cades/reference/cadescom/cadescom_interface/icpsigneddata2enhancecades)

Лучше его делать на сервере. На клиенте обычно нет лицензии на это. Нужны дополнительные лицензии на проверку отзыва и клиентов сервера таймштампов. Ещё нужен [сервер таймштампов](https://www.cryptopro.ru/forum2/default.aspx?g=posts&t=20958).

```
import pycades
import sys
import base64
import json

def amplify(inp, outp, hashvalue, hashtype):

    hashedData = pycades.HashedData()

    hashedData.Algorithm = hashtype
    hashedData.DataEncoding = pycades.CADESCOM_BASE64_TO_BINARY
    hashedData.SetHashValue( hashvalue)

    signature = inp.read()
    signedData = pycades.SignedData()

    signedData.VerifyHash(hashedData, signature, pycades.CADESCOM_CADES_BES)

    sys.stderr.write('Verification successful')
    sys.stderr.write('\n')
    sys.stderr.flush()


    sformat = pycades.CADESCOM_CADES_X_LONG_TYPE_1
    #sformat = pycades.CADESCOM_CADES_T

    TSAAddress="http://....../tsp.srf"

    tsignature = signedData.EnhanceCades(sformat, TSAAddress)

    outp.write('-----BEGIN PKCS7-----\n')
    outp.write(tsignature)
    outp.write('\n-----END PKCS7-----\n')
```

Код на python. inp - файл подписи pksc7 без усиления, outp - файл подписи с усилением.  hashvalue, hashtype - значения хеша, возможно можно достать из самой подписи, но у меня в проекте они отдельно прилетают - не стал копаться.